# Where does the comma go in the Birkas Kohanim, and why?

Tags: tefilla, grammar-dikduk, birchas-kohanim

In which of the positions (1) or (2) does the comma go in the introduction to [Birkas Kohanim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priestly_Blessing),

> ברכנו בברכה המשלשת (1) בתורה (2) הכתובה על ידי משה עבדך
>
> Bless us with the blessing which is tripled (1) in the Torah (2) which is written through Moshe Your servant.

(free translation)

and why?
I have seen siddurim with both versions.

Comment: I've thought about this, and I've concluded that it makes little difference, because the sentence, contextually, makes sense - but has problems - with either parsing. There really ought to be no comma, IMHO, but when reading it you instinctively want there to be one.

Comment: @SethJ, The essential question is, I think, whether "which is written" modifies "the blessing" or "the Torah." A properly-placed comma would serve to disambiguate.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, but they are both written, "at the hands of Moshe [HaShem's] servant."

Comment: @SethJ, That's true, but the intent of the composer of this prayer (AKH"G?) was probably to indicate one or the other.

Comment: @SethJ Same here, but it sounds much better to me with the comma in the first position because a) the phrase "המשולשת בתורה" would be very strange and not in keeping with the ways (משולש(ת is used in the תורה, and even more convincingly, b) הכתובה על ידי משה is parallel to האמורה מפי אהרן and the latter can only refer to this ברכה, not the entire תורה (unless you say כהנים were the פוסקים and therefore "said" the תורה as well...).

Comment: And I think by "comma" we are all just referring to a subordinate phrase boundary and not an actual comma.

Comment: Where are the other two times it is written in the Torah?

Comment: In  R' Jonathan Sacks' Koren sidur, it gives both punctuations, one of them in the alternate texts section at the end of the sidur.

Answer (score 2):

This question was discussed [in the Forum Otzar](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=34325) and the following authorities are quoted there which prefer the version with the pause after  בתורה

ברכנו בברכה המשלשת  בתורה **,** הכתובה על ידי משה עבדך

1. ילקוט יוסף קצוש"ע אורח חיים סימן קכח - הלכות נשיאת כפים
2. שו"ת יביע אומר ח"ח או"ח סימן יא אות כב:
   who quotes

-- (הרד"א (דף לב רע"ד,

-- (רבי יהודה בן יקר בפירוש התפלות והברכות (עמוד סו,

-- ס' המנהיג and

-- Shmuel Ungvar in Hameor (link on the Forum Otzar page)

The one authority that has  the comma after the word 
המשלשת is

שו"ת איש מצליח חלק א סימן כ .

Comment: I believe R JB Soloveitchik also preferred the pause after המשלשת.

Answer (score 1):

Per Artscroll - Nusach Sefard after המשלשת, Nusach Ashkenaz after בתורה.

Comment: Is that a difference that Artscroll affirmatively describes, or something you infer by looking at different editions? In the latter case, it's quite possible that the placement of the comma was a function of day on which it was typeset rather than of the nusach of the edition.

Comment: All the Ashkenaz Artscroll Sidurim have it one way and all the Sefard ones have it the other way.

Comment: How many did you check?

Comment: @GershonGold, _all_ the different editions?

Comment: Yes all the Artscroll Ashkenaz have it one way and all the Sefard have it the other way.

Answer (score 1):

[R. Yosef Eliyahu Henkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Eliyahu_Henkin) has a responsum in which he addresses common errors relating to the placement of commas in prayer. The case in question here is one of the examples he mentions, and he states that it should be recited with the comma between "משולשת" and "בתורה" (i.e. position 1 in the question).

**Shu"t Gevuros Eliyahu 1:15**

> א) דבר פלא ומכאיב הוא שדוקא קריעת שמע שהוא דאורייתא וקבלת עול מלכות
>   שמים הדרך הוא שכל כך חוטפים בזה עד שבלי ספק שאין זה בכלל קריאה לשום
>   מ"ד והיותר פלא שאפילו בשבת ויו"ט שמאריכין בתפלה הנה בקריאת שמע דוקא
>   חוטפים ובבתי החסידים מחלקים ברכת יוצר לפסקי פסקי וגם מזמרים הרבה בזה
>   [אגב לענ"ד יש בשירה ריקנית מבלי תיבות התפלה משום חשש הפסק בברכה ואין
>   ראיה מהגדולים שעשו כן שהם עשו מתוך התלהבות ורגש פנימי ובאופן זה הוא
>   בכלל קריאה ולא כן לדידן] ובהגיע לקריאת שמע חוטפים אותו כרגע ואי לדידי
>   צייתי היו מתקנים לקרוא קריאת שמע תמיד בבית הכנסת פסוקים פסוקים הש"ץ עם
>   הצבור וכל שכן בשבת ויו"ט ותמור זה לקצר בשאר דברים שאינם חיוביים ומקום
>   שאמרו להאריך דהיינו בקריאת שמע אינם רשאים לקצר
>
> ב) וראיתי להעיר שמה שיש חזנים נוהגים לומר חתימת "גאל ישראל" בלחש הוא
>   שלא כדין כי תקמת חכמים שהש"ץ יתפלל בקול מיוצר עד אחר שמונה עשרה בכדי
>   להוציא את מי שאינו בקי ואפילו כשכולם בקיאים התקנה קיימת ואף שאצלנו
>   אומר הש"ץ רוב הברכות בלחש הוא משום שבדיעבד יוצאיםבקיצור של כל הברכה עם
>   מה שאומר סמוך לחתימה אבל על כל פנים הפתיחה של הברכה שפותחת בברוך
>   והחתימה ומעט מעין החתימה סמוך לה מחוייב לאמור בקול רם ועל כן גם תחילת
>   ברכת יוצר ומעריב ערבים צריך הש"ץ לאמר בקול רם [ומנהג הספרדים שהש"ץ
>   אומר בקול רם כל התפלה] וכן הוא מדינא דגמרא
>
> ג) ואזכיר כאן מקומות בתפלה שהרבה משתבשים בסדורי התבות ואציין בזה הסדור
>   הנכון [ביוצר] "קדושה כולם כאחד עונים – ואומרים ביראה קדוש כו'" "לעומתם
>   משבחים – ואומרים ברוך כו'" "הודו והמליכו – ואמרו ה' ימלוך לעולם ועד"
>   "לך ענו שירה בשמחה רבה – ואמרו כולם מי כמוך כו'" "זה אלי ענו – ואמרו
>   ה' ימלוך כו'" "ימלוך ה' לעולם – אלהיך ציון לדור ודור"1
>
> בקדושת שחרית דשבת "כי מחכים אנחנו לך מתי תמלוך – בציון בקרוב בימינו
>   לעולם ועד תשכון" בקדושת מוסף צריך הש"ץ בתחלה לומר בקול רם "ובדברי קדשך
>   כתוב לאמר" ואחר כך יאמר הקהל "ימלוך" "לדביר ביתך – ואשי ישראל ותפלתם"
>   [כן משמע מהמשך הלשון וגם מהתוס' (מנחות קי. ד"ה ומיכאל) והטור (סי' קכ)
>   לעיקר ונראה לי הפירוש דכשישב העבודה אז יקבל ברצון האשים עם התפלות]
>   בברכה המשולשת – בתורה הכתובה" [מצות ברכת כהנים תורה קרי לה"

As noted by Double AA, this was also printed in [עדות לישראל](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2274&st=&pgnum=162&hilite=).

Comment: Can you post the whole text of the Teshuvah please?

Comment: Would it be acceptable according to halacha to scan it and post it as an image or is copyright an issue (a question for MY)?